# React bug useState updated automaticlly

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks

Hello i have a bug that im trying to fix.
I have this useState and inside it is an array with an object inside 
`const [statistikat, setStatistikat] = useState([{}]);`

Now in another component im declaring another useState to get the value of statistikat and change something inside it

```
const [newStatsObj, setNewStatsObj] = useState(() => {

let muaj;
let cmimiPerDit;
if (dtSot.getMonth() === 5) muaj = "qershor";
if (dtSot.getMonth() === 6) muaj = "korrig";
if (dtSot.getMonth() === 7) muaj = "gusht";

if (dataForSpecific.dhoma === "dhomTeke") cmimiPerDit = 100;
if (dataForSpecific.dhoma === "dhomCift") cmimiPerDit = 120;
if (dataForSpecific.dhoma === "dhomFamiljare") cmimiPerDit = 150;

let newStatObj = statistikat[0];//here im pasing the value of statistikat to another variable

//Then im updating the object that i get from statistikat
newStatObj[`fitimetSezon${dtSot.getFullYear()}`][muaj][
  dtSot.getDate() - 1
] += Number(cmimiPerDit);

return newStatObj;//then im returning the updated object to my new use state
```

});

The problem is than after this function inside the **newStatsObj** runs and return the required value also **statistikat** useState get updated. 
Idon't know if it is a problem with **useState hook** but thanks very much who answer!

Comment: JavaScript in general uses reference semantics. You are not *pasing the value of statistikat to another variable*, you are *creating a reference to the same object*. Since they are the same object, changes are visible in both.

Comment: But how to pass the value? itryed and this but again dosent work {...statistikat[0]}

Comment: @super thanks for answering but i found a way to do it making a deep copy af the object like this to my variable JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(statistikat[0]))

Comment: Depends what the objects contains. If it contains another object that too need to be cloned. This is what's usually refered to as deep copy.  You can use `structuredClone` if your runtime is fairly new. The old way to do it was normally `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`.